# No Neutral Wire to Install Smart 3 Way Dimmer

Tags: wiring, grounding, neutral, smart-switch

I am replacing a 3 Way switch (master) and remote dimmer with Decora Smart devices.  The master has the correct wires to install the smart 3-way dimmer master.  The remote box had a dimmer device with a line?, travel, ground and another wire (load?) that did not connect to any of the wires in the master box. The remote box does not have a neutral wire.  Instead, the ground wire is tied to the neutral wires in both boxes.

My 2 questions: 1) How do I find and detach the neutral to ground connection if needed? 2) Can I use the other black wire (former load?) as a neutral wire. The Leviton Decora Remote (DD00R-DLZ) does not required a load connection because the traveler signals the master box to turn on/off the circuit?

Comment: Ground/neutral problem may be a biggie. Can you upload pictures of the wires going to **both** of the existing 3-way switches?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in both boxes, please?

Comment: The trick with 3-way circuits is *you don't get to decide which one is master and which one is remote.  The wiring in the walls decides that for you.*

Comment: Leviton has other models that don’t require a neutral. But you can change your wiring. Where is your feeder? It may be at the light fixture itself by the way you stated with a line? We need to know where things are to get them wired properly.